# Database design for reservation of computers in laboratories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I want to create an application for enabling the users to book the computers in a laboratory if they want to use it from a specific time to time.The users can book the computers for their next 15 days. So,how should I design the database for this application.

Comment: Hi. Time to read a textbook on information modeling, the relational model & database design. This is too broad a question. Please see [ask] & other [help] links & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Also hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. For when you do ask about a specific design attempt read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

1. Start by defining what your entities and attibutes will be. It's better if you can do a Conceptual Design first.
2. Than you design it logically.

For example, your entities might be:

---

USERS, COMPUTERS, RESERVATIONS.
Your attributes might be:

USERS (**SomeUniquePersonalIDnumber**, Name, Surname, Email*, PhoneNumber*)

PrimaryKey in bold. With asterisk *Optional

COMPUTERS (**UniqueComputerSerialNumber**, NumberOfComputerInLab)

RESERVATIONS (**AutoincrementNumber**, **UserPK**, **ComputerPK**, DateOfReservation, TimeFrom, TimeTill)

PrimaryKey composed of the three attibutes making it unique. Same user might reserve the same computer over time but the AutoincrementNumber field will make the composite PK unique.

RESERVATIONS(UserPK) referencing USER(SomeUniquePersonalIDnumber)
RESERVATIONS(ComputerPK) referencing COMPUTERS(UniqueComputerSerialNumber)

---

3. Define what type of fields will those attributes be
   (Integer/Varchar/...) based on the querying language you will want
   to use.
4. Translate all of above into commands to create the database, the
   tables etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just pick a piece of paper and start with normalization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.

If I look for entities in your question I see the following entities:

```
user

computer

booking
```

Then you need to figure out what properties belong to those entities and the relation between them. You can create an ERD if you like and start creating Ruby on Rails models.

In Ruby on Rails if you generate a model the model has a created_at datetime field by default. I think you can use that to figure out the specific time and check if 15 days are past since this booking is created.